# Aggregating HTTP Response Codes for Reporting in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, http-status-code-404

I am new to the Windows IIS environment, coming from Linux/Apache. At my new job (ASP.NET shop), they don't currently monitor 404s or any other non-200 HTTP response codes so problems with missing images and files from the website or 500 errors don't surface until a customer emails us weeks later.

What do you guys use to monitor, aggregate and display these responses in .NET? In my old job, I had a script attached to the 404 handler that inserted into a database and from there I created a dashboard that grouped and displayed all the 404s so it was easy to see issues with missing files, etc.

Not sure if it's best to handle at the application level or with some log file aggregator.

What is the best practice for doing the same in ASP.NET?

I appreciate any advice on this

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at [`ELMAH`](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) which is specifically designed for this purpose.